# Simple Injector - Subscribing to an event with the += operator (plus equals) like Ninject's OnActivation

Tags: c#, events, event-handling, simple-injector

I'm trying to subscribe to an event using Simple Injector. My class has:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public event Action<MyClass> SomeEvent;
    //...
}
```

With Ninject, it can be done with `OnActivation()`:

```
Bind<MyClass>().ToSelf()
    .OnActivation((context, myObj) =>
    {
        myObj.SomeEvent += MyStaticEventHandler.Handle; // for static
        // or...
        myObj.SomeEvent += context.Kernel.Get<MyEventHandler>().Handle; // for non-static
    });
```

How is this done with Simple Injector? I tried looking around, but only found content on `IEventHandler`/`ICommandHandler` implementations, none using C# events.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The equivalent to Ninject's `OnActivation` in Simple Injector is `RegisterInitializer`. Your code example translates to the following Simple Injector code:

```
container.Register<MyClass>();
container.RegisterInitializer<MyClass>(myObj =>
{
    myObj.SomeEvent += MyStaticEventHandler.Handle; // for static
    // or...
    myObj.SomeEvent += container.GetInstance<MyEventHandler>().Handle; // for non-static
});
```

However, you should typically prefer using Constructor Injection as a mechanism to decouple classes over the use of events. You achieve the same amount of decoupling with Constructor Injection when you *program against interfaces*.

Using Constructor Injection has the advantage that:

- The container can analyse object graphs for you and detect any configuration pitfalls such as [Captive Dependencies](https://blog.ploeh.dk/2014/06/02/captive-dependency/).
- It improves discoverability, because an interface is less abstract than an event, which allows a reader to understand what the class is using and allows to easily navigate to an implementation.
- It prevents [Temporal Coupling](https://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/05/24/DesignSmellTemporalCoupling/).

Comment: Awesome! Great answer, I'll certainly rethink this part of my design, thanks a lot!